# Dropna only on the last n rows Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to clean a dataset.
In the last 3 rows, I know if the column "B" is empty drop the whole row.
I haven't managed to figure out how to use dropna only on certain rows.

```
   A   B 
1  1   3
2  5
3  6   5 
4  2
5  3   6
```

Needs to become

```
   A   B 
1  1   3
2  5
3  6   5 
5  3   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You slice the last three row then apply your condition pass that to `drop`

```
n=3
df=df.drop(df.tail(n).B.eq('').loc[lambda x : x].index)
   A  B
1  1  3
2  5   
3  6  5
5  3  6
```

Comment: Thanks, that was great. I actually had to use df=df.drop(df.tail(n).B.isnull().loc[lambda x : x].index) because my values were "None" but yeah that was correct.